# How to download only Android ICS Source Code

Tags: android, osx-lion, android-source

This was the first time i'm downloding the source code.

I'm a Mac User I want to download ICS source Code so, i have installed all the dependencies that was present in "[source.android.com](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)"
after i have executed

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest 
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1
```

then the download started and till now it has downloaded like 3GB and it's still going on r the above lines i have given are correct r am i downloding the whole Android Versions becz it was mentioned that the source code is like 2GB i guess.

What is the actual size of the source code??

Comment: The source code itself is a lot smaller than 2GB. Git, the versioning system used for Android, keeps the entire history of the project with each download. That includes all previous versions of Android, up to ICS.

Comment: oh nooo. . .then i only want to download ICS Source Code then what should i do. . how to do that?? plzz :|

Answer (score 1):

repo init is for initializing the repo directories.( this first command you gave will give you the master, if you want ics use only second command for repo init).
After that has finished you need to do repo sync

Total source code size is about 9 -10 gb for ics